# Рекурсивная функция для подсчёта суммы цифр числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Дано натуральное число N. Вычислите сумму его цифр. Где я накосячил? 
P.S не нужно предлагать мне решение циклами. Меня интересует именно логика отработки моего кода. Почему именно мой код не отрабатывает?

```
a = input()
a = str(a)
result = 0
count = 0
def summa_cifr(a, count, result):
    c = ''
    c = c + a[count]
    c = int(c)
    result = result + c
    if count < len(a):
        return summa_cifr(a,count+1, result)
    else:
        return result
summa_cifr(a, count, result)
print(result)
```

Comment: Вас не смущает использование result как глобальной переменной, как аргумента функции и для возврата значения функции? Что будет, когда `count = len(a) -1`? P.S. Использование строк здесь ни к чему

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, было бо полезно рассмотреть различные рекурсивные решения данной задачи.

Вот однострочное рекурсивное решение, работающее с целыми числами без преобразования в строки:

```
def sum_digits(num):
    return num%10 + sum_digits(num//10) if num > 9 else num
```

примеры работы:

```
In [17]: sum_digits(123)
Out[17]: 6

In [18]: sum_digits(1234567)
Out[18]: 28

In [19]: sum_digits(8)
Out[19]: 8
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = input()
a = str(a)
def summa_cifr(a, count, result):
    c = ''
    c = c + a[count]
    c = int(c)
    result = result + c
    if count < len(a)-1:
        return summa_cifr(a,count+1, result)
    else:
        return result
print(summa_cifr(a, 0, 0))
```